# In a thread of emails, how to reply to the last sender that isn't you?

Tags: mutt

In GMail, if you reply the last message in a thread, the message is sent to the person you are exchanging messages with, does not matter whether you were the last person to send a message. In Mutt, if you reply the last message and it is yours, it sends the e-mail to yourself and not to the other person. How can I emulate the gmail behaviour in Mutt?

Simply replying the last message sent by the person excludes my message from the thread.

Perfect, thank you @derobert. For the sake of completeness, here are the additions in the muttrc that solved the problem:

set reply_self = no
alternates "emailA@yourDomain.com|emailB@yourDomain.com"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`set reply_self = no`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#reply-self) (which should be the default, but confirm you and/or your distro hasn't changed it). You may also need to use `alternates` so that Mutt knows all of your email addresses.